# Warning from tsc even though file is excluded

Tags: typescript, tslint, tsc, tsconfig

I have a file, 'survey.d.ts' in this location 'src/app/dynamic-pages/survey.d.ts'. In my tsconfig.json, I add this glob to the excludes array. "exclude": ["src/app/**/*.d.ts"]

Annoyingly I still get warning for this file. The file has the comment `/* tslint:disable */` on the first line. Can someone tell me why the warnings are still showing up?

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh right, the project uses eslint, even though it is a TS project. The correct comment for my case was /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */ at the top of the file.